# Can instances with internal load balancing visibility send data outside of the VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have two Elastic Beanstalk instances inside the same VPC -- one with public load balancing (internet accessible), one with internal load balancing only.

For extra security, I'd like the internal instance to be completely siloed from the public internet -- no data can enter and no data can exit unless it is through another instance in my VPC.

Is what I am looking for, a "siloed" instance, accomplished by making my load balancer VPC internal only? That is, can that the internal only instance make a request to `www.google.com` (or another random site) while inside the VPC, or will it not be able to get outside of the VPC? Or alternatively do I need to set outbound security groups to prohibit all traffic not to my other instances.

This is the internal setting I am talking about in Elastic Beanstalk:

**Visibility**: Internal

`Make your load balancer internal if your application serves requests only from connected VPCs. Public load balancers serve requests from the Internet.`

---

As a side note, I have set my security groups so that the only outbound connection is the load balancer and VPC security group. But I am wondering if internal load balancing takes that a step further, regardless of what I set in my outbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

An internal load balancer will/can route traffic to both instances within a Public Subnet or a Private Subnet. Routing traffic via an internal load balancer does not affect or impact the visibility of the instances to or from which the traffic is routed from the load balancer.